# Is it possible to get exact geo location of a device without third party APIss using ionic in android app?

Tags: ionic-framework, geolocation

I need to get a exact location of a device in android app using ionic.
I have used capacitor/geolocation plugin to capture the location. But it is grabbing latitude and longitude 50 to 200 meter away from the location.

Is it possible to get exact geo location of a device without third party APIs ?

I have used capacitor/geolocation plugin to capture the location.

Comment: No it is not possible. capacitor/geolocation plugin is as best as you can get without creating your own custom capacitor plugin.

Comment: you can enable high accuracy. but it will still differ around 20 to 50 meters.

Comment: Yes, with enable high accuracy it is showing 20 to 1000m away.